# make images change opacity after hovering over separate text with React

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks, hover

in the process of learning React and making a small practice website. On one of my pages i've got a CSS Grid with a central grid square that has text in it and surrounding the text are multiple images. In the text i've put spans on certain words to make them different colour and each word has a corresponding Image around it somewhere.

```
  <div className="gridBox">
          {/* About Heading Sq */}
          <div className="grdSq--0">
            <div className="aboutBox">
              <p>
                <span className="about">About</span>
                <br />
                <span className="me">me</span>
              </p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <span>Born</span>: 1992
                </li>
                <li>
                  Graduated <span>Highschool</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Lived in <span>Europe</span> for a Year
                </li>
                <li>
                  Worked As A <span>Waiter</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Loves Working in The <span>Garden</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Worked as a <span>Tiler/Landscaper</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Became a Student at <span>42</span>: 2020
                </li>
                <li>
                  Trainee Software Engineer at <span>SRA</span>: 2022
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* highschool */}
          <div className="grdSq--1">
            <div className="grdImg grdImg--1"></div>
          </div>
          {/* 42 */}
          <div className="grdSq--2">
            <div value={2} className="grdImg  grdImg--2"></div>
          </div>
          {/* born */}
          <div className="grdSq--3">
            <div className="grdImg grdImg--3"></div>
          </div>
          {/* tradie */}
          <div className="grdSq--4">
            <div className="grdImg grdImg--4"></div>
          </div>
          {/* waiter*/}
          <div className="grdSq--5">
            <div className="grdImg grdImg--5"></div>
          </div>
          {/* travel */}
          <div className="grdSq--6">
            <div className="grdImg grdImg--6"></div>
          </div>
          {/* garden */}
          <div className="grdSq--7">
            <div className="grdImg grdImg--7"></div>
          </div>

          <div className="grdSq--8">
            <div className="grdImg grdImg--8"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is what my code is currently set out like

What i want to do is make it so that onHovering over one of the span words the corresponding image will change from opacity 0 to 1. I'm very unclear on how to achieve this, if i need to useState or use onHover and using events or what. Some clarity on which way to go would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events to set state to a specific number, name or id, which can then be used to change the opacity of the corresponding image with that number, name or id.

Initiate the state as follows:

```
const [hoveredImage, setHoveredImage] = useState("")
```

Then, at each span, create events that trigger a change in state like:

```
<span onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredImage("born")} onMouseLeave={() => setHoveredImage("")}>Born</span>
```

Finally, use the state to change the opacity of the images:

```
{/* born */}
 <div className="grdSq--3" style={hoveredImage === "born" ? {opacity: 1} : {opacity: 0}}>
     <div className="grdImg grdImg--3"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i had literally just tried something very similar to this and it broke but this is very helpful i can see now where my syntax was out!